# What is the correct way to load datasource into listView in React Native

Tags: react-native

### What is the correct way to load datasource into listview in React Native?

At the moment I'm doing it like below. It works, but before adopting this concept on all my lists I'd like some input. Is this a good way of doing it? My original data lives in an Immutable.List.

For readers not used to Immutable.js: The difference from using a plain array is that we need to call *theList.get(rowId)* instead of simply *theArray[rowId]*. We also need to convert the index list to an array, *keySeq().toArray()*

In the constructur I initialize this.state with a dataSource on which I also perform the initial cloning of data with a separate function (cloneDataSource):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      getRowData: (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[sectionId].get(rowId),
      sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
  })

  this.state = {
    dataSource: this.cloneDataSource(dataSource)
  }
}
```

The function for cloning data rows are called from both the constructor and from componentWillReceiveProps. This particular listView has two hardcoded sections:

```
cloneDataSource(dataSource) {
  return dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(
    [
      this.props.activeProjects,
      this.props.inactiveProjects
    ],
    [0,1],
    [
      this.props.activeProjects.keySeq().toArray(),
      this.props.inactiveProjects.keySeq().toArray()
    ]
  )
}

componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
  this.setState({dataSource: this.cloneDataSource(this.state.dataSource)})
}
```

The fact that I need to call my clone function twice worries me. Why won't it suffice to clone the data at componentWillReceiveProps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot only use `componentWillReceiveProps` because it [*doesn't run on the first render*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) and you have to use `nextProps`, not `this.props`. If your `ListView`'s data is coming from the top as `props`, you're always going to need two spots where you'll update the `ListView.DataSource`. One for the initial render and the other for updates coming in. One way to keep things DRY-ish is to do this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    // You can initialize it directly on to the state object
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      getRowData: (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[sectionId].get(rowId),
      sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
    }),
  };
}

componentWillMount() { // Or `componentDidMount`
  // 1. For initial render (note: I'm passing this.props, you'll see why on 2.)
  this.updateDataSource(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // 2. For updates
  // (note: you must pass `nextProps` because 
  // `this.props` has not been updated)
  this.updateDataSource(nextProps); 
}

// Do your thing
updateDataSource(data) {
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(
      [
        data.activeProjects,
        data.inactiveProjects
      ],
      [0, 1],
      [
        data.activeProjects.keySeq().toArray(),
        data.inactiveProjects.keySeq().toArray()
      ]
    )
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, you should note that not all `props` will be in `nextProps` because only the props that changed are in `newProps`, so you should properly handle making sure that the prop fields actually exist.

Comment: Great, thank you. It felt kind of wrong to do it twice, but it's ok now when I know why. I actually had the dataCloning in componentWillUpdate at first, but I moved it to the constructor to have it where the datasource is created. That's also why I initialize it in a separate variable (not in this.state) so I could send it to my clone function in a clean way. That refactor is also where I lost "nextProps". Thank you for catching that one.

Comment: About your edit: Do you mean that I need something like this at the top of the update function: if(!data) return; data.activeProjects = data.activeProjects || this.props.activeProjects; data.inactiveProjects = data.inactiveProjects || this.props.inactiveProjects;

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, I don't think you need to check whether `data` exists. It will exist otherwise that life cycle callback would never be called (not 100% sure but it would make sense).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You have been of great help. Now I can continue on this path with more confidence.